# Divide bargraph of population number by proportion older than 70

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have population numbers for four countries. I'd like to display the population number on a bargraph and then seperate each bar into two parts, where one indicates the proportion of the population older than 70.

For example:

```
country<-c("Germany","South Africa","Australia","Austria")
population<-c(100,300,430,200)
propolder70<-c(10,30,43,20)
data<-cbind(country,population,propolder70)
```

I would like to do this with ggplot, but I am not sure how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version using `tidyverse`. Create a `data.frame`, calculate the number over and under 70, then reformat the data to longform, then plot.

```
data.frame(country = c("Germany","South Africa","Australia","Austria"),
       population = c(100,300,430,200),
       propolder70 = c(10,30,43,20)) %>% 
  mutate(over_70 = population * propolder70 / 100,
        under_70 = population - over_70) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(over_70, under_70)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(country, value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col()
```